# Grails Spring Security Username globally

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am learning the ins and outs of Spring Security...it has been slow going...

Right now I'm trying to access the currently logged in users Username from the index.gsp page. I have code that works from Controllers, but I can't get the code right for any other pages. I have a feeling I am missing something key in regards to the User object.

Here's what I use for my controller:

```
class BookController {

    def springSecurityService

    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "POST", delete: "POST"]


    def index() {
        redirect(action: "list", params: params)
    }

    def list(Integer max) {
        def userDetails = springSecurityService.principal
        params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
        [bookInstanceList: Book.list(params), bookInstanceTotal: Book.count(), muds: userDetails]
    }
...
... etc
...
```

Then in the View (gsp) I can simply do something like:

```
Username: ${muds.getUsername() }
```

How would I do this in index.gsp?

Answer (score 4):

You are better off using the built in tag library that comes with the plugin. The [documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/helperClasses.html#securityTagLib) shows all the various tags, one of which is for getting properties of the current logged in user. As an example:

```
<sec:loggedInUserInfo field="username"/>
```

Comment: Do I need additional plugins for the taglib? I'm getting this error: Error processing GroovyPageView: Unknown JSP tag sec:loggedInUserInfo

Comment: No. What version of the spring security core plugin are you using?

Comment: spring-security-core:1.2.7.3

Comment: Try doing a grails clean

Comment: I do a clean often...still not working. At the top of my GSP I have: <%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %> which the Ec lipse IDE says: "Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"

Comment: You don't need to import the tag library in a GSP page.

Comment: Oh, and no errors on Clean...no errors on Compile...no errors on buildign the war. I get the error above when deployed to Tomcat...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47693/discussion-between-joshua-moore-and-bean)

Comment: Joshua, I appreciate your help...would you have any other ideas what could be the problem...?

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any errors with ${muds.getUsername() }? Try using just ${muds} or better check the class of ${muds}